# Time interval not changing after repeated function call

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

The goal of my code is to call a function every 5 seconds, which it succeeds in doing so. The issue is that when I declare my seconds variable every time, it does not change even though the start date should not be changing.

```
func timedUpdate()
{

    let initialBank = 2000
    let dateOfInstallation = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "installDate")
    let seconds = date.timeIntervalSince(dateOfInstallation as! Date) / 8.64

    let bestStreak = (UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "bestStreak"))
    let days = seconds / 86400


    print(seconds/8.64)
    print(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "bestStreak")!)

    if (Int(days) > bestStreak)
    {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(days, forKey: "bestStreak")
    }

    bestStreakLabel.text = "\(Int(bestStreak)) Days"
    currentStreakLabel.text = "\(Int(days)) Days"
    currentStreakBar.progress = CGFloat(Float(days)/Float(bestStreak))
    bestStreakBar.progress = 1

    getTodaysSteps { [weak self] steps in
        self?.bankTotalLabel.text = "\(Int(steps) - Int(seconds/8.64) + Int(initialBank))"
        self?.circleLabel.progress = Double(((Double(steps) - Double(seconds) + Double(initialBank))) / 10000)

        if (Int(steps) - Int(seconds) + Int(initialBank) < 0)
        {
            // Will Eventually need a popup screen here to say you lost and streak is reset to 0
            self?.resetApp()
        }
    }
}
```

When I print the value of seconds, it is always the same decimal, very close to 0. Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Why are you dividing `seconds` by `8.64` when you first initialize it and then again when you print? You're essentially dividing the seconds by `74.6496` before printing.

Comment: Where is your `date` object instantiated? Are you sure at least one of `date` and `dateOfInstallation` changes between your function calls?

Comment: Just edited that in the code, thank you. The numbers that were printed changed, but are still not changing after each function call.

Comment: The only place that the date changes is in the resetApp() function, which should not be running in this piece of code.

Comment: `date` only changes in `resetApp()` --- which ***is not*** running in this piece of code. So... `dateOfInstallation` never changes and `date` never changes, which means --- `date.timeIntervalSince(dateOfInstallation as! Date)` will never change.

Comment: I moved my date = Date() to the timedUpdate() function and everything is working. Thank you!